# javascript file have error : prompt is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie with javascript and I am writing a very simple javascript according to the textbook and here is the code

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;
var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;

while (isSunk == false) {
  guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):") // prompt instead of promt
  if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
    alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
  } else {
    guesses = guesses + 1;
    if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
      alert("HIT!");
      hits = hits + 1;
      if (hits == 3) {
        isSunk = true;
        alert("You sank my battleship!");
      }
    } else {
      alert("MISS");
    }
  }
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +
  "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3 / guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Then, I installed nodejs, and tried to run this file by many ways. but it said to me many error.
The 1st error is, when I ran it directly

```
Object expected
800A138F
microsoft jscript runtime error
```

the second error is, when I ran it by the command `node battleship.js`, here is the error
[image: the error about the command "node battleship.js]

As you can see in the picture, it said to me that promt is not defined.
My problem is, I ran another code no problem. Which means nodejs no problem.
And, I ran my code online no problem, which means my code no problem.

So, how can I fix this one ? Could you please help me with this ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: How can you use `prompt` on the server-side...Is this a part of API? If you looking for `prompt` that works exactly like in clien-size then It's not available on the server-side...

Comment: [How do I prompt users for input from a command-line script?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291909/prompt-not-defined-using-node-from-command-line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one use "prompt" and "alert" javascript commands in webstorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417359/how-does-one-use-prompt-and-alert-javascript-commands-in-webstorm)

Comment: Copy and paste your code to the console chrome dev tool then hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js isn't the same as running javascript in the browser, it doesn't have the window object, which has things like `prompt()` or `alert()`. in browsers, those show up as a pop-up.

Instead of `alert()`, you can probably just use `console.log()`, and for `prompt()`, you can look at this https://nodejs.dev/learn/accept-input-from-the-command-line-in-nodejs

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

readline.question(`What's your name?`, name => {
    console.log(`Hi ${name}!`)
    readline.close()
})
```